# UITableView Leaving a Big Gap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So i have been struggling with his trouble that if UITableView returns no data it leaves a big gap.. and if it returns data it is fine..

The Image which shows the error is below.

[Comments leaves a big gap if their is no comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YBAh.png)

[If their is data in the tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YBAh.png)

i want the tableView to finish at the cell before where the comments start.

This is the code for the TableView Data Source..

```
   // MARK: - Table view data source

        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
            return 1
        }


        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
             return 9 + comments.count
        }


          override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

             if indexPath.row == 0 {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! vlcTableViewCell

                // Configure the cell
                cell.viewsCount.text = "\(shot.viewsCount)"
                cell.likesCount.text = "\(shot.likesCount)"
                cell.commentCount.text = "\(shot.commentCount)"


             return cell
            } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! descCell

               // Configure the Cell
                cell.usernameLabel.text = "\(shot.user.username)"
                cell.descriptionLabel.text = "\(shot.description)"
                cell.profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: shot.user.avatarUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "2"))


            return cell
            } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell3", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            return cell
            } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell4", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! teamCell
                if shot.team == nil{
                  cell.teamNameLabel.text = "Team"
                } else {
                cell.teamNameLabel.text = "\(shot.team.name)"
                }
            return cell
            } else  if indexPath.row == 4 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell5", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! reboundShotsCount
                cell.reboundCountLabel.text = "\(shot.reboundCount)"
                return cell
             } else if indexPath.row == 5 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell6", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
                 return cell
             } else if indexPath.row == 6 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell7", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! attachmentShotsCount
                cell.attachmentCountLabel.text =  "\(shot.attachmentsCount)"

                return cell
             } else if indexPath.row == 7 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell8", forIndexPath: indexPath)
                return cell
             } else if indexPath.row == 8 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell9", forIndexPath: indexPath)
                return cell
             } else {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell10", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentCell

                //let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
                //cell.nameLabel.text = comment.user.name


                return cell
            }
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
          // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the height for each cell

             if indexPath.row == 0 {
                 return 55.0
            } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
             return 55.0
            } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
              return 40.0
            } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
                if shot.team == nil {
                 return 0.0
                }else {
                  return 40.0
                }
              } else if indexPath.row == 4 {
             if shot.reboundCount == 0 {
                return 0.0
             } else {
              return 37.0
             }
            } else if indexPath.row == 5 {
             if shot.reboundCount == 0 {
                return 0.0
             } else {
               return 90.0
             }
            } else if indexPath.row == 6 {
             if shot.attachmentsCount == 0 {
              return 0.0
             } else {
             return 37.0
            }
            } else if indexPath.row == 7 {
             if shot.attachmentsCount == 0 {
              return 0.0
             } else {
             return 90.0
            }
            } else if indexPath.row == 8 {
              return 40.0
           } else {
              // This is the code for the comment cells
                if shot.commentCount == 0 {
                 return 0.0
                } else {
              return 70.0
                }
             }
            }
        }
```

the code for my headerView is below..

```
  var headerView : UIView!

    let device = Device()
    private var kTableHeaderHeight : CGFloat = 300.0

   @IBOutlet weak var bgImageView: FLAnimatedImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if device == .iPhone6sPlus{
          kTableHeaderHeight = 300.0
        } else if device == .iPhone6 {
         kTableHeaderHeight = 300.0
        } else if device == .iPhone5s {
         kTableHeaderHeight = 225.0
        } else if device == .iPhone4s {
         kTableHeaderHeight = 200.0
        } else if device == .iPhone4 {
          kTableHeaderHeight = 200.0
        } else  if device == .Simulator(.iPhone6sPlus){
         kTableHeaderHeight = 300.0
        } else {
          kTableHeaderHeight  = 250.0
        }



        title = shot.title

       //The code for the headerView
       headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView
       tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
       tableView.addSubview(headerView)

        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: kTableHeaderHeight,   left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -kTableHeaderHeight)
 }
```

and the code for updateHeaderView

```
func updateHeaderView(){
     var headerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -kTableHeaderHeight, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: kTableHeaderHeight)
        if tableView.contentOffset.y < -kTableHeaderHeight {
          headerRect.origin.y = tableView.contentOffset.y
          headerRect.size.height = -tableView.contentOffset.y
        }
     headerView.frame = headerRect
    }
```

Then update headerView in UIScrollViewDelegate method

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateHeaderView()
    }
```

and if i use this method.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return kTableHeaderHeight
    }
```

it will give some weird 2 headers.. i cant post the picture as i have crossed the links limit..

Thanks in advance 
 Aryan

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check your table header size .

Comment: I have edited the question with all methods to do with the headerView as i implemented stretchy headerView @sourav

Comment: even i get rid of the stretchy header method i still get that problem.. @sourav and my tableHeaderSize varies on the device type..

Comment: @ Aryan Kashyap, I could not get what you want exactly . all 2 images seems normal (1st one having data 2nd one having no data) . and what dose this imply "tableView to finish at the cell before where the comments start." (how you suppose to know that your table view dose not end there ?)

Comment: i mean the tableView leaves a big gap if their are no comments but i want the tableView to finish at the cell before the comments start to show.. if their are no comments.. @sourav

Comment: As your numberOfRowsInSection is 9 + comment.cout ... it will minimum return 9 when comment.count = 0 . and in heightForRowAtIndex you have written " if indexPath.row == 0 {
                 return 55.0
            } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
             return 55.0
            } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
              return 40.0
            } "   so you will always get 55+55+40 = 150 (which i guess is your problem)

Comment: Hi @sourav now I'm gonna try by making a different section for the comments..